# How to write HTML code of main.

Tags: html

code necessary to place a layer "main" so left edge is 33.3% from left edge plus 7 pixels? . Im not sure how to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS calc function for the element you want to position this way.

```
left:calc(33.3% + 7px);
```

Example

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  left:calc(33.3% + 7px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```